# Full Text Index search in sub query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm try to write a t-sql query like this:

```sql
select * from table1 t1
where exists (select * from table2 where CONTAINS(Col1, t1.Col1))
```

But the error is:

> Incorrect syntax near 't1'.

There is a FTI on table2 with Col1 included. It's working fine when I hardcode a value like this:

```sql
select * from table2 where CONTAINS(Col1, 'value here')
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You can't do this in a join, the `CONTAINS` parameter must be a constant or variable. Annoying, but that's how it is. One possibility is to build a dynamic query of all parameters, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316315/220697

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for clarifying. I'll find an alternative solution.